# Cannot find dependency when running krakenjs generator

Tags: node.js, yo, kraken.js

I have been trying to generate a stub service following the quickstart from the readme for [krakenjs](https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-swaggerize) However, when I get to the gen step:

```
$ yo swaggerize
```

I get the following error:

```
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../../lib/util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymac/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/generator-swaggerize/generators/app/index.js:5:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

No amount of googling seems to find a solution that works for me. I am just trying to PoC several generators for my team.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mymac/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/generator-swaggerize/generators/app/index.js:5:12)`

I've compared the folder structure of the module on this line with the [git repo](https://github.com/krakenjs/generator-swaggerize/tree/master), and it seems like your version of the module is from the v3.x branch. I could reproduce the error installing the `generator-swaggerize@3.0.0-alpha.1` build with npm.

I checked the code in the repo and it seems like the package.json of this branch is misconfigured, so when you `npm install` it, it doesn't install all the required files for the module to run.

Long story short, you seem to have an early alpha/development version of `generator-swaggerize` that simply doesn't work.
Not sure how you ended up with that, but you should be able to fix it with installing a stable version.

`npm install -g generator-swaggerize@latest`

2.0.2 seems to be the latest working version.